# 403 Errors on Apache server

Tags: linux, apache, centos

I changed home directory of Apache "/var/www/html" into "/gwanwoonam/web"
After that, web server returns 403 Error - Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /info.php on this server.
How Can I fixed that

I googled, and found Solution on permission and SELinux.
I turned off SELinux, So It is disabled.

```
[gwanwoonam@localhost web]$ getenforce
Disabled
```

Secondly I tried to edit conf file
         sudo vim /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    #Require all denied
    Require all granted
    Allow from all
</Directory>
...
DocumentRoot "/home/gwanwoonam/web"
...
<Directory "/home/gwanwoonam/web">
    AllowOverride None
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
    Allow from all
</Directory>
...
<Directory "/home/gwanwoonam/web">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride None

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
    Allow from all
</Directory>
...
```

And, I put the permission 777 at web directory, sub folder and files of it.

```
drwxrwxrwx. 2 gwanwoonam gwanwoonam   40 Jul 21 12:19 web
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 gwanwoonam gwanwoonam 106 Jul 21 11:52 index.html
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 gwanwoonam gwanwoonam  66 Jul 21 12:19 info.php
```

However, I cannot solve this problem..
How Can I find solution?

---

LOGS

```
[Sun Jul 21 14:04:57.852935 2019] [core:error] [pid 1918] (13)Permission denied: [client ::1:51512] AH00035: access to /favicon.ico denied (filesystem path '/home/gwanwoonam/web') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path, referer: localhost 
[Sun Jul 21 14:05:00.422975 2019] [core:error] [pid 1923] (13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:42228] AH00035: access to / denied (filesystem path '/home/gwanwoonam/web') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
```

Comment: You get a 403 with every requests?  What do the logs say?  access and error.

Comment: [Sun Jul 21 14:04:57.852935 2019] [core:error] [pid 1918] (13)Permission denied: [client ::1:51512] AH00035: access to /favicon.ico denied (filesystem path '/home/gwanwoonam/web') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path, referer: http://localhost/
[Sun Jul 21 14:05:00.422975 2019] [core:error] [pid 1923] (13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:42228] AH00035: access to / denied (filesystem path '/home/gwanwoonam/web') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path

Comment: I copied your logs in your question.  Remember that you can always edit your question.  Comments are hard to read for logs or code.

Answer (score 0):

In your question you showed this:

```
drwxrwxrwx. 2 gwanwoonam gwanwoonam   40 Jul 21 12:19 web
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 gwanwoonam gwanwoonam 106 Jul 21 11:52 index.html
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 gwanwoonam gwanwoonam  66 Jul 21 12:19 info.php
```

Note that `index.html` and `info.php` are **not** under the `web` directory.  Therefore Apache cannot find them since you told it `DocumentRoot "/home/gwanwoonam/web"`.

Move your files into `/home/gwanwoonam/web`, then Apache will see them.

---

Then, to ensure you do not have a permissions issue, at the filesystem level, run this:

```
chmod 755 /home/gwanwoonam/web
find /home/gwanwoonam/web -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find /home/gwanwoonam/web -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

This will put permissions 
    `drwxr-xr-x` on all directories (including `/home/gwanwoonam/web`)
and 
    `-rw-r--r--` on files.

This way your Apache should be able to read all files under `web`, and return them back to you.

Answer (score 0):

Add the line below to your existing code:

```
restorecon -r /home/gwanwoonam/web
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that.